# How do I check that a list of cells have the correct values in Excel, where some cells can have more than one correct value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, if

I'm trying to create a "Complete?" box for a spreadsheet I'm making of certain cocktails and the necessary ingredients for each. I've managed to wriggle everything into acknowledging if individual cells are correct, but when it comes to checking if *everything* is correct, this is where I'm having trouble.

My current working plan is using a massive =IF(AND( formula, where A1="XXX", A2="YYY" etc. which has worked for some.

However for some cocktails, I've got some cells (juices, syrups etc) where there's more than one ingredient in that category so I need to ensure that in either of the boxes that more than one option is plausible. As I mentioned, I've got this done on the level of individual cells, and I can input either or and the correct volume of each ingredient as displayed by the conditional formatting of the cells, but when I try to incorporate an OR statement into the IF(AND( string, it stops acknowleding the fact that cells are indeed cells.

My listed example comes at I20 in my spreadsheet, where the first entry of I20 is highlighted but the I20 entry after the OR and all other cells after that are not recognised as cells and just is recognised as I20 as though I wrote any random word.

```
=IF(AND(I4="Coupette", I5="Shot of Bottega Millesimato", I6="Shake & Double Strain", I10="Better Bitters", L10="1 Dash", I12="Havana 3", L12="2 Shots (50ml)", (I20="Lime Juice" OR I20="Pineapple Juice"), (L20="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)" OR L20="1 Shot (25ml)"), (I21="Pineapple Juice" OR I21="Lime Juice"), (L21="1 Shot (25ml)" OR L21="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)"), I22="Passionfruit Pureé", L22="1 Shot (25ml)", I23="Vanilla Syrup", L23="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)"), COUNTBLANK(H3:L27)=89, TRUE, FALSE)
```

As mentioned, I20 and onwards is where my problem lies, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post some sample data using [Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) with the expected output.

Comment: Fix your `OR()` syntax. Could you try based on your OP: `=IF(AND(I4="Coupette",I5="Shot of Bottega Millesimato",I6="Shake & Double Strain",I10="Better Bitters",L10="1 Dash",I12="Havana 3",L12="2 Shots (50ml)",OR(I20="Lime Juice",I20="Pineapple Juice"),OR(L20="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)",L20="1 Shot (25ml)"),OR(I21="Pineapple Juice",I21="Lime Juice"),OR(L21="1 Shot (25ml)",L21="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)"),I22="Passionfruit Pureé",L22="1 Shot (25ml)",  I23="Vanilla Syrup",L23="1/2 Shot (12.5ml)",COUNTBLANK(H3:L27)=89), TRUE, FALSE)` but you will need to fix the `COUNTBLANK()` not sure why you are using it

Comment: Just In case you don't know about this... use Formulas > Evaluate Formula to Step into a formula and see in more detail where a problem occurs.

Comment: @Stax when user enters the formula they have posted in OP will get an error message, saying **`there is a problem with the formula`**, because the `OR()` syntax is not correctly written. So they wont be able to use the `Evaluate` option until and unless they are fixing the `OR()` at first.

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya Yes, but I meant in general, and earlier in the formula crafting process. Also, Adam: Generally, to quickly find out the Syntax, select a blank cell for the example and then search for the function in the dialogue that opens when clicking the FX button in the formula bar, However, the search function isn't very good. For instance, searching for "OR" yields many things in the "Recommended" category, but Not "OR". In this case, change the category to "All", and look through the alphabetically sorted list.

Comment: @Stax I agree with you, thanks for informing OP about `Evaluate` feature. Helps in finding errors if any.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya  ,,, instead of posting solution as a comment ,,, better post it as Answer ,,,,, !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha Sir, it is not clear to me, whether it will work for OP or not, I have just adjusted the `OR()` syntax, user needs to clarify further, but they are yet to reply on the same, hence not posted. Not sure of the use of `COUNTBLANK()` function in the formula. Seems like redundant here, waiting for response

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya since your suggestion is too long and I do believe it's not suitable to the comment,,,, so that I've suggested to post it as an answer,,,, if unfortunately some one down vote then U loose on 2 points,, but if OP will accept U get 15 RP.

Comment: Understood sir, thanks for the clarifications